# How do I pass my JSON string using Flask?

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I have created a JSON string. It looks like this:

```
{
 "version": 1,
 "type": "exercise",
 "Exercises": {
  "Exercises": [
   {
    "Overhead Press": [
     {
      "id": 1,
      "interval": 10,
      "resistance": 55,
      "set_number": 1,
      "workout_id": 2,
      "workout_date": "2022-01-03T06:00",
      "exercise_id": 1,
      "exercise_name": "Overhead Press"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

I created it using `json.dumps` like this: `json_exercise_col = json.dumps(exercise_col, default=default, indent=1)`

I think my `json` string is good. I could be wrong so I have included it to have a second pair of eyes on it.

I pass it through like this:

`return render_template("graph.html", graph_exercises=json_exercise_col, dropdown_menu=unique_exercise_names)`

Now all I want to do is print it to my `console.log`. I use this:
`console.log({{graph_exercises}})`

I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break`

I have tried this explination of parsing JSON strings:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

When I do their simple example it works.

```
const g = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const l = JSON.parse(g)
console.log(l);
```

But when I try to do it with my string passed using Flask it does not.

```
const f = JSON.parse('{{graph_exercises}}')
console.log(f)
```

What am I missing here? Is there something special I need to do because I'm passing it through Flask? Am I just using `JSON.parse()` incorrectly?

Source for the HTML / JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
    const g = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
    const l = JSON.parse(g)
    console.log(l);
    const f = JSON.parse('{
 &#34;version&#34;: 1,
 &#34;type&#34;: &#34;exercise&#34;,
 &#34;Exercises&#34;: {
  &#34;Exercises&#34;: [
   {
    &#34;Overhead Press&#34;: [
     {
      &#34;id&#34;: 1,
      &#34;interval&#34;: 10,
      &#34;resistance&#34;: 55,
      &#34;set_number&#34;: 1,
      &#34;workout_id&#34;: 2,
      &#34;workout_date&#34;: &#34;2022-01-03T06:00&#34;,
      &#34;exercise_id&#34;: 1,
      &#34;exercise_name&#34;: &#34;Overhead Press&#34;
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}')
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML / JS source look like? Use the _"View page source"_ option in your browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your first example

```js
const g = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const l = JSON.parse(g)
console.log(l);
```

The `g` variable is an object which can be parsed. Now if you look at the example from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) you can see `JSON.parse` being used as so:

```js
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

With your example you're not passing any JSON it looks like you're just passing a string that's wrapped in `{{ ... }}`

You could either export your JSON to a variable and pass that. So like the following:

```js
const someJson = graph_exercises
const parsedJson = JSON.parse(someJson)
```

But a few things here...

- 1. Your question has a lot of JS and very little Python so things aren't too clear without seeing the code in the files.
- 2. I would stop using just letters for variable names, eventually it will not be clear to you in your code base what is what.
- 3. What I think you really need is an understanding of Jinja templates.

#### 3

You say you're importing the JSON into your template like so:

```py
render_template("graph.html", graph_exercises=json_exercise_col, dropdown_menu=unique_exercise_names)
```

In `graph.html` you're able to access `graph_exercises` within your html by using Jinja. So you could use Jinja to loop through your JSON. Something like ....

```html
<div>
  {% for graph in graph_exercises | safe %}  
    <span id="exercise">{{graph.type}}</span>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As a very basic example. You can find more information on Jinja here:

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/

https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/itdtix/flask_json_parsing_and_structure_with_jinja_for/

Comment: I agree on point 2. I only use single letters variable names when I am testing something I don't understand. You mean to tell me all I had to do to parse my `JSON` string was to first pass it into a `const` before passing it to `JSON.parse()`? I'm going to try that now.

Comment: I must be understanding this incorrectly. Is there something wrong with my `JSON` string? I am getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data`.  This is what line 1 column 2 looks like: `'{&#34;version&#34;: 1,`

Comment: So, I'm realizing that this is an issue with passing the JSON string using Flask. I know I could just replace `&#34;` with `"` by using `str.replace(&#34;, "\"")`. Is there a better way?

Comment: you don't need to use `&#34;` you can just use `{"something": "foobar", "more": "hello world"}`. You never see JSON with the `&#34;`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON scroll down to the code example. That's how it should be formatted...

Comment: But again you don't need to do what you're doing if you're passing into your template like you are...you can just use Jinja.

Comment: Ahh I believe the naming of my variable is causing confusion. `graph_exercises` does not hold the graphs themselves. It is the `JSON` string with all the raw data. It has many different exercises in it. I want to be able to parse through different exercises and update the graph when the user selects a different one through a drop down menu.

Comment: oh...then could you not just pass `graph_exercises` into your script  within your html? Like `const f = JSON.parse(graph_exercises)` as the way you're doing it...it will be available within your your template. You could then use it within your script how you please?

Comment: That was the plan. It just took a while to figure out that &#34; was my problem with parsing this string the whole time.

Comment: Turns out all I really need to do is let Jinja know that the JSON string was safe. `{{graph_exercises | safe}}`

Comment: nice...you can mark my answer correct...although i did give you the Jinja hint haha

Comment: Yeah. Just add the `{{graph_exercises | safe}}` so that everyone knows it was a formatting issue. Just so they can see that in your answer instead of the comments.